# Trying to identify matching cells randomly distributed in 2 seperate Excel sheets, and have the matching data copied and pasted into a third sheet

Tags: vba, excel

So I have several worksheets on the same Excel workbook that I need to compare. Worksheet 1 is the masterlist, and I need to compare worksheets 1-2, 1-3, 1-4. I then need to paste any similar 1-2 data cells in column A of worksheet 5, and similar 1-3 data cells in column B of worksheet 5, and 1-4 similarities to column C of worksheet 5. For starters I have focused on getting the 1-2 comparison to work. So far I have been able to get my test number to be pasted to cell A1 of sheet 5. I am running into trouble because it only works for 1 cell, and I cannot get the program to paste a similarity in A1, and then A2... etc, when I have multiple similar items. They just overwrite each other in cell A1, or in the entire A column. I am also running into trouble because the program as it is written stops when it hits a blank space, but I need it to just skip the blanks and read the next cell when it comes across them. This is because my data sheets are very messy and the data is scattered over several thousands of rows among several different columns, with spaces randomly interjected. Below is my working code for just reading a similarity, and pasting it into A1. I should note that I have considered adding a specific cell range depending on which sheet I am on in order to put an end point on the program, but I haven't quite figured out how to work it in.

```
Sub findDuplicates()
' code to find duplicates in 2 different worksheets

Dim rng1, rng2, rngA, cell1, cell2 As Range
' 4 ranges have been defined

Set rng1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C:C")
'rng1 defines the existing data in column C and worksheet1

Set rng2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C:C")
'rng2 defines the data in column C and worksheet2

Set rngA = Sheets("Sheet5").Range("A1")

For Each cell1 In rng1
    If IsEmpty(cell1.Value) Then Exit For
    'check for empty rows. If true then exit the program

    For Each cell2 In rng2
        If IsEmpty(cell2.Value) Then Exit For

        If cell1.Value = cell2.Value Then
            'compare data in cell1 and cell2 and then copy/paste if they have equal values
            cell1.Copy
            Sheets("Sheet5").Select
            rngA.Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
        End If
        'run the looping process
    Next cell2
Next cell1

End Sub
```

The general idea of what I imagine the program to look like would be something like

```
Define ranges

Block of code that runs through each cell in sheet 1 comparing it to all cells in sheet 2.

Block of code that, when similarities are found, copy/paste that cell on sheet 1 to sheet 5 column A

*Program resumes scan from the next cell on sheet 1*

Block of code that breaks the program when it hits the end of the specified cell range
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated! You would be saving me at least a week's worth of mindless work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few comments about your code:

- `Dim rng1, rng2, rngA, cell1, cell2 As Range` means only `cell2` is defined `As Range`, while `rng1, rng2, rngA, cell1` defined `As Variant`
- You don't need to have 2 `For` loops to compare, you can replace the second `For` loop with the `Match` function, it will save you precious run-time.
- You need to find the next empty row in "Sheet5", by using `NextRow = Sheets("Sheet5").Cells(Sheets("Sheet5").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1`
- Last, you don't need to `Select` the sheets in order to copy>>paste, you can so it in 1-line (see in my code below).

***Code***

```
Sub findDuplicates()
' code to find duplicates in 2 different worksheets

' 4 ranges have been defined
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rngA As Range, cell1 As Range, cell2 As Range
Dim NextRow As Long


'rng1 defines the existing data in column C and "Sheet1"
Set rng1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C:C")

'rng2 defines the data in column C and "Sheet2"
Set rng2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C:C")

Set rngA = Sheets("Sheet5").Range("A1")

For Each cell1 In rng1
    If Not IsEmpty(cell1.Value) Then ' only check non-empty cells
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(cell1.Value, rng2 , 0)) Then ' <-- confirm match was asuccessful
            ' find next empty row in column "A" in "Sheet5"
            NextRow = Sheets("Sheet5").Cells(Sheets("Sheet5").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            ' Copy >> Paste in 1 line (without need to Select the Sheets)
            cell1.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet5").Range("A" & NextRow)
        End If
        'run the looping process
    End If
Next cell1

End Sub
```

Comment: This gave me a runtime error 5, Invalid procedure call or argument

Comment: @TheGusBus at which line ?

Comment: It doesn't specify it just pops up with a window

Comment: @TheGusBus run the code in debug mode (with F8) and see what line

Comment: `cell2` in the match needs to be `rng2`

Comment: When I press F8 into this line it pops up  : NextRow = Sheets("Sheet5").Cells(Sheets("Sheet5").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

Comment: oh ok nvm substituting rng2 in for cell2 fixed it

Comment: @TheGusBus now it's your part, where you mark this as "ANSWER"

Comment: I do have another question though, the script runs fine when I am searching in a single column C:C, or D:D, but what if I want to search across six different columns? Like A:D or A1:D200? When I try that it comes up blank

Comment: @TheGusBus you mean `rng2` is across 4-5 columns ?

Comment: yes both rng1 and rng 2 are across 4-5 columns, and in some cases up to 16K rows

Comment: not sure, what type of comparison are you trying to make when you have 2 ranges of 4-5 columns width ? find exact match for all cells in a certain row ? or find one match from each row ?

Comment: I am trying to see if a certain number "938394" for example, exists anywhere in the second spreadsheet, and if it does, copy and paste that number to spreadsheet 5. I think I can use your code to do it though by reorganizing my data into one single column

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that rngA points to A1 and nothing changes that.
Add one line after your paste command:

```
ActiveSheet.Paste
Set rngA = rngA.Offset(1,0)  ' This will move the pasting location one step down
```